# Feature map for the Gaussian kernel

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

In SVM, the Gaussian kernel is defined as:
$$K(x,y)=\exp\left({-\frac{\|x-y\|_2^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)=\phi(x)^T\phi(y)$$ where $x, y\in \mathbb{R^n}$.
I do not know the explicit equation of $\phi$. I want to know it.

I also want to know whether
$$\sum_ic_i\phi(x_i)=\phi \left(\sum_ic_ix_i \right)$$ where $c_i\in \mathbb R$. Now, I think it is not equal, because using a kernel handles the situation where the linear classier does not work. I know $\phi$ projects x to a infinite space. So if it still remains linear, no matter how many dimensions it is, svm still can not make a good classification.

Comment: why does this kernel imply a transformation? Or are you referring to the associated feature space?

Comment: Yes, what is the feature space $\phi(\cdot)$ so that $\phi^T(x)\phi(x^{'}) = exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\|x-x^{'}\|^2)$

Answer (score 34):

You can obtain the explicit equation of $\phi$ for the Gaussian kernel via the Tailor series expansion of $e^x$. For notational simplicity, assume $x\in \mathbb{R}^1$:

$$\phi(x) = e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2} \Big[ 1, \sqrt{\frac{1}{1!\sigma^2}}x,\sqrt{\frac{1}{2!\sigma^4}}x^2,\sqrt{\frac{1}{3!\sigma^6}}x^3,\ldots\Big]^T$$

This is also discussed in more detail in [these slides](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/kuleuven_svm.pdf) by Chih-Jen Lin of NTU (slide 11 specifically). Note that in the slides $\gamma=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$ is used as kernel parameter.

The equation in the OP only holds for the linear kernel.

Comment: Hi, but this equation above only suit one dimension.

Comment: So, here, the reproducing kernel Hilbert space is a subspace of $\ell^2$, correct?

Comment: Is there also an explicit representation of the Laplacian kernel?

Answer (score 13):

For any valid psd kernel $k : \mathcal X \times \mathcal X \to \mathbb R$, there exists a feature map $\varphi : \mathcal X \to \mathcal H$ such that $k(x, y) = \langle \varphi(x), \varphi(y) \rangle_{\mathcal H}$. The space $\mathcal H$ and embedding $\varphi$ in fact need not be unique, but there is an important unique $\mathcal H$ known as the reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS).

The RKHS is discussed by: Steinwart, Hush and Scovel, *An Explicit Description of the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces of Gaussian RBF Kernels*, IEEE Transactions on Information Theory 2006 ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2006.881713), [free citeseer pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101033442/https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.107&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

It's somewhat complicated, and they need to analyze it via the extension of the Gaussian kernel to complex inputs and outputs, but it boils down to this: define $e_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as
$$
e_n(x) := \sqrt{\frac{(2 \sigma^2)^n}{n!}} x^n e^{-\sigma^2 x^2}
$$
and, for a tuple $\nu = (\nu_1, \cdots, \nu_d) \in \mathbb N_0^d$, its tensor product $e_\nu : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ as
$$
e_\nu(x) = e_{\nu_1}(x_1) \cdots e_{\nu_d}(x_d) 
.$$
Then their Proposition 3.6 says that any function $f \in \mathcal H_\sigma$, the RKHS for a Gaussian kernel of bandwidth $\sigma > 0$, can be written as
$$
f(x)
= \sum_{\nu \in \mathbb N_0^d} b_\nu e_\nu(x)
\qquad
\lVert f \rVert_{\mathcal H_\sigma(X)}^2
= \sum_{\nu \in \mathbb N_0^d} b_\nu^2
.$$

We can think of $\mathcal H_\sigma$ as being essentially the space of square-summable coefficients $(b_\nu)_{\nu \in \mathbb N_0^d}$.

The question remains, though: what is the the sequence $b_\nu$ for the function $\phi(x)$? The paper doesn't seem to directly answer this question (unless I'm missing it as an obvious implication somewhere).

---

The do also give a more straightforward embedding into $L_2(\mathbb R^d)$, the Hilbert space of square-integrable functions from $\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$:
$$
\Phi(x) = \frac{(2 \sigma)^{\frac{d}{2}}}{\pi^{\frac{d}{4}}} e^{- 2 \sigma^2 \lVert x - \cdot \rVert_2^2}
.$$
Note that $\Phi(x)$ is itself a function from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R$.
It's basically the density of a $d$-dimensional Gaussian with mean $x$ and covariance $\frac{1}{4 \sigma^2} I$; only the normalizing constant is different.
Thus when we take
$$\langle \Phi(x), \Phi(y) \rangle_{L_2}
= \int [\Phi(x)](t) \; [\Phi(y)](t) \,\mathrm d t
,$$
we're taking the [product of Gaussian density functions](http://blog.jafma.net/2010/11/09/the-product-of-two-gaussian-pdfs-is-not-a-pdf-but-is-gaussian-a-k-a-loving-algebra/), which is itself a certain constant times a Gaussian density functions. When you do that integral by $t$, then, the constant that falls out ends up being exactly $k(x, y)$.

---

These are not the only embeddings that work.

Another is based on the Fourier transform, which [the celebrated paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3182-random-features-for-large-scale-kernel-machines.pdf) of Rahimi and Recht (*Random Features for Large-Scale Kernel Machines*, NIPS 2007) approximates to great effect.

You can also do it using Taylor series: effectively the infinite version of Cotter, Keshet, and Srebro, *Explicit Approximations of the Gaussian Kernel*, [arXiv:1109.4603](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4603).

Comment: Douglas Zare gave a 1d version of the "more straightforward" embedding in an interesting thread [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35638/9964).

Comment: Here you find a more 'intuitive' explanation that the $\Phi$ can map onto a spave of dimension equal to the size of the training sample, even for an infinite training sample: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80398/svm-in%EF%AC%81nite-dimensional-feature-space/168309#168309

Comment: thank you very much for these resources! surprisingly hard to find stuff that goes deeper than a blog post, but is also specific to RBFs

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that your second equation will only be true if $\phi$ is a [linear mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) (and hence $K$ is a linear kernel).  As the Gaussian kernel is non-linear, the equality will not hold (except perhaps in the limit as $\sigma$ goes to zero).

Comment: thank you for your answer. When $\sigma\rightarrow 0$, the dimension of the Gaussian kernel projects would increase. And by your inspiration, now I think it is not equal. Because, using kernel just handle the situation that linear classification does not work.

Answer (score 7):

## EXPLICIT EXPRESSION AND DERIVATION VIA DIRECT PROOF

The explicit expression for $\phi$ you are asking for is the following:

### Lemma:

> Given the Gaussian RBF Kernel $K_\sigma$ between two $n$-dimensional vectors ($x$ and another), for each $j$ from 0 to infinity and for every combination of $n$ indices (labeled as $k$) that add up to $j$, the feature vector $\phi(x)$ has a feature that looks like this:

$$
\phi_{\sigma, j, k}(x) =  c_{\sigma, j}(x) \cdot f_{j, k}(x)
$$

Where:

$$
\begin{aligned}
c_{\sigma, j}(x) &= \frac{K_\sigma(x, 0)}{\sigma^j \sqrt{j!}}\\
f_{j, k}(x) &= \begin{pmatrix} j\\k_1,k_2, \dots, k_n \end{pmatrix}^{\frac{1}{2}} \prod_{d=1}^n{x_d^{k_d}}
\end{aligned}
$$

This can be directly derived as follows:

---

### Definitions:

- Gaussian RBF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function
- Taylor expansion of the exponential function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function
- Multinomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

$$
\begin{aligned}
K_\sigma(x, y) = &e^{-\frac{\|x-y\|_2^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
\epsilon := &e^{\frac{1}{\sigma^2}}\\
\epsilon^x = &\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left\{ \frac{x^j}{\sigma^{2j} \cdot j!} \right\}\\
(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n)^j = &\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=j}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} j\\k_1,k_2, \dots, k_n \end{pmatrix} \prod_{d=1}^n{x_d^{k_d}} \right\}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

---

### Direct Proof:

First, we decompose the squared euclidean distance into its components, and perform the Taylor expansion for the $xy$ component:

$$
\begin{aligned}
K(x,y)= &e^{-\frac{\|x-y\|_2^2}{2\sigma^2}} =\epsilon^{\langle x, y \rangle} \cdot\epsilon^{-\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{2}} \cdot \epsilon^{-\frac{\|y\|_2^2}{2}}\\
= &\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left\{ \frac{\langle x, y \rangle^j}{\sigma^{2j} \cdot j!} \right\} \cdot\epsilon^{-\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{2}} \cdot \epsilon^{-\frac{\|y\|_2^2}{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

For further convenience, we refactor the expression (using $c$ for more compact notation):

$$
\begin{aligned}
K(x,y) = &\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left\{\frac{\epsilon^{-\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{2}}}{\sigma^j \cdot \sqrt{j!}} \cdot \frac{\epsilon^{-\frac{\|y\|_2^2}{2}}}{\sigma^j \cdot \sqrt{j!}}  \cdot \langle x, y \rangle^j \right\}\\
= &\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left\{ c_{\sigma, j}(x) \cdot c_{\sigma, j}(y)  \cdot \langle x, y \rangle^j \right\}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

And with help of the multinomial theorem, we can express the power of the dot product as follows (using $f$ for more compact notation):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle x, y \rangle^j = &\left(\sum_{d=1}^n x_d y_d \right)^j\\
 = &\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=j}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} j\\k_1,k_2, \dots, k_n \end{pmatrix} \prod_{d=1}^n{(x_dy_d)^{k_d}} \right\}\\
= &\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=j}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} j\\k_1,\dots, k_n \end{pmatrix}^{\frac{1}{2}} \prod_{d=1}^n{x_d^{k_d}}   \cdot  
\begin{pmatrix} j\\k_1, \dots, k_n \end{pmatrix}^{\frac{1}{2}} \prod_{d=1}^n{y_d^{k_d}}   \right\}\\
=: &\sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=j}\left\{f_{j,k}(x) \cdot f_{j, k}(y)  \right\}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now replacing in $K$ will allow us to end the proof:

$$
\begin{aligned}
K(x,y) = &\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left\{ c_{\sigma, j}(x) \cdot c_{\sigma, j}(y)  \cdot \sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=j}\left\{f_{j,k}(x) \cdot f_{j, k}(y)  \right\} \right\}\\
= &\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k_1+k_2+\dots+k_n=j}\left\{ c_{\sigma, j}(x) f_{j,k}(x) \cdot c_{\sigma, j}(y) f_{j, k}(y)  \right\}\\
= &\langle \phi(x), \phi(y) \rangle\\
&\square
\end{aligned}
$$

Where each $\phi$ is a vector with one entry for every combination of $n$ indices (labeled as $k$) that add up to $j$, and this for each $j$ from 0 to infinity.

---

hope this helps! Cheers,
Andres

Comment: This should be the top answer man. Good Job!

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helps

Comment: explicit and clear