# Is it always possible to find the feature map from a given kernel?

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick, feature-engineering

Each positive definite kernel $k(x, x')$ used in machine learning/statistics has an equivalent representation as a dot product of the feature map representation $\phi(x)$ of each input i.e.

\begin{align}
k(x, x') = \phi(x)^T\phi(x')
\end{align}

My question is given a kernel expression, is it always possible to find the corresponding feature map? For example, we know that the corresponding feature map of gaussian kernel is an infinite dimensional vector. ([Feature map for the Gaussian kernel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69759/feature-map-for-the-gaussian-kernel))

Any pointers (including research papers) are welcome.

Comment: Note that if you want a $\phi$ you can use in practice, you can often find _approximate_ feature maps; random Fourier features are one example for shift-invariant kernels $k(x, y) = \psi(x - y)$, or the Nyström method works for any kernel but is data-dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: It depends on what you mean by find and the precise kind of kernel you are looking at. In many cases you can prove the abstract existence of such a feature map but in practice it is always hard and generally impossible to "write it down". Furthermore, the constructions are mathematically subtle. You need to be careful about technical assumptions.

### Background

Let your kernel be defined as $K:\Omega\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (the domain is important!). There are many feature maps in the sense that a feature map is an embedding of $\Omega$ into a suitable Hilbert space. Of course, there is always the canonical feature map: $\Phi:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^\Omega, x\mapsto K(x,\cdot).$ Judging from the right hand side of your equation you are looking for a different feature map, one which maps into "vectors" i.e. $l^2$ which is the Hilbert space of square summable sequences with the canonical scalar product $<x,x>=\sum_i x_i x_i$ aka "$x^Tx".$

### Mercer's Theorem

Key fact to obtain such a feature map is Mercer's theorem (see Theorem 4.49 in [1]). If your kernel $K$ is continuous and its domain of definition $\Omega$ compact, then the map defined on square integrable functions
$$ M_K: L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega), f\mapsto \int_\Omega f(t)K(t,\cdot)dt$$
is a so called Hilbert-Schmidt operator. The theory of these operators tells us that there exists a countable family of functions $\phi_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which spans $L^2(\Omega)$ such that one can write the kernel $K$ as
$$ K(x,y) = \sum \phi_i(x)\phi_i(y),$$
which, of course, is exactly the feature map you are looking for.

### Further aspects

- To find the $\phi_i$ explicitly you need to find all solutions to the integral equation $M_K(\phi)=\lambda \phi$. This is very hard (or impossible) in general.
- Even this special kind of feature map is not unique. There will be other families $\psi_i$ which also allow such a representation.
- The feature map depends not only on the Kernel $K$ but also on its domain $\Omega$.

[1]: Ingo Steinwart; Andreas Christmann "Support Vector Machines"

Comment: Thank you for the answer.