# Dimensions of feature transfrom $\phi(x)$ for a kernel Support Vector Machines

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

Given a kernel function $K(x, x') = \langle \phi(x), \phi(x') \rangle$, how can we figure out the dimensions of the feature transform $\phi(x)$?

For example, for $K(x, x') = (1+x^Tx')^M$

Comment: Possible related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436971/