# Kernel transformation in Machine Learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, kernel-trick

I understand kernels allow us to linearly separate non-linearly separable data in a higher-dimensional space.

Given a feature vector **$\bar x = [x1,x2,..xn]^T$**, we can apply the transformation **$\phi(\bar x)$**, and apply the usual regression **$ y = \bar w^T\phi(\bar x)$**.

However, I do not understand the notation in the following question:

***Given N data points $(x,t)$ (scalars), fit an th degree polynomial using polynomial and Gaussian kernels, and study goodness of fit.***

---

To be more specific, what function $\phi$ do I use in the Polynomial and Gaussian kernels to obtain the transformed input vector?

Comment: Can you be specific about what part of the question you do not understand? What have you tried & where are you stuck?

Comment: I do not understand how to explicitly transform the input data and perform regression

Comment: Seems like the question wants you to 1) generate data from any degree M polynomial 2) perform polynomial regression on this data 3) perform kernel regression on this data. Is that right? Like, you're given an X, but not a t?

Comment: I am given a set of (x,t) both are scalars. When it says fit an Mth degree polynomial, I'm guessing I need to create a vector for each $x_i->[x^0,...x^M]$ and perform a kernel transformation on these input vectors. What I do not get is how do I use kernels ($\phi(\bar x)$) to transform these vectors.

Comment: [The feature maps for the Gaussian kernel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69759/feature-map-for-the-gaussian-kernel)

Comment: I was confused whether we use the explicit representation as in $\phi(\bar x)$ or do it implicitly using the Gram matrix $K$; $K(i,j)$ = $<\phi(\bar x_j),\phi(\bar x_i)>$. Then we can proceed to use the least-squares solution to compute the optimum $\bar \alpha$ estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused whether we use the explicit representation as in $\phi(\bar x)$ or do it implicitly using the Gram matrix $K$; $K(i,j)$ = $<\phi(\bar x_j),\phi(\bar x_i)>$.
To have $\phi$ transform data into an $infinite$-dimensional space for the Gaussian, we use the implicit representation, and then we can proceed to use the least-squares solution to compute the optimum $\bar \alpha$ estimate.

$\bar \alpha$ = $ (K + \lambda I)^{-1}Y$, where  $\lambda$ is the regularisation parameter and $Y$ is the target variable.

The estimate $\hat Y(i)$ = $\bar \alpha'k(\bar x_j,\bar x_j)$

For the polynomial kernel of order d: $K(i,j)$= $\ <\phi(\bar x_j),\phi(\bar x_i)>\  =(\bar x_j'\bar x_i)^d $

For the Gaussian kernel of variance $\sigma ^2$: $K(i,j) =\  <\phi(\bar x_j),\phi(\bar x_i)>\  = e^{(||\bar x_j-\bar x_i||)/2\sigma^2}/\sqrt(2\pi \sigma ^2) $

Comment: can see different Kernels [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html)

Comment: on [Lagrange Dual Problem](https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machines-learning-data-science-step-by-step-f2a569d90f76) as about Kernel-trick - if your data would appear to solve XOR-problem once