# What is test and what is training data in this SVM formula?

Tags: svm, cross-validation

I am studying how to use Gaussian RBF kernels for mapping 2D data to 3D. In this link: [Use Gaussian RBF kernel for mapping of 2D data to 3D](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63881/use-gaussian-rbf-kernel-for-mapping-of-2d-data-to-3d), @MaxS provides an answer on this topic, but I can't understand this formula:

$$ \newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
z(\x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\exp\left\{-\frac{||\x-\x_i||^2}{2\gamma^2}\right\}  
$$

- If I want to use SVM, is $\x$ the test data?
- Is $n$ number of training data?
- Is $\x_i$ one of training data in this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to 1 and 3. $n$ is the number of support vectors, which is typically less than the number of training instances.

Comment: thanks,can you explain more it for me? do you mean that after we used SVM, we can define z for our new data? and why can not we use all training data? I really appreciate you for your help.

Comment: I search about this and think that because the value of alpha is zero for nsv you said n is number of support vectors,Am I right?

Comment: @nnpnnp yes that is right!