# Proof that exponential of a kernel is a kernel

Tags: kernel-trick

How can I prove that the exponential $\exp(K)$ of a kernel function $K$ is again a kernel? I think it can be proved using Taylor expansion but I am not sure how.

Comment: You almost have it! You surely need the Taylor expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential). You need to prove that is positive definite. If A > 0, are its powers positive?

Comment: everything you need is in Dougal's answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35634/how-to-prove-that-the-radial-basis-function-is-a-kernel/150964#150964

Comment: Sometimes, $K$ is not a kernel and you still have to prove that the exponential function is a valid kernel, say $\exp(-\theta|x-x'|)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Taylor expansion around $0$:

$$
\exp(K) = \exp(0) + \exp(0)K + \frac{\exp(0)}{2!}K^2 + \frac{\exp(0)}{3!}K^3 + ...\\
\exp(K) = 1 + K + \frac{1}{2}K^2 + \frac{1}{6}K^3+...
$$

we can see that the exponential of a kernel is just an infinite series of multiplications and additions of that kernel.

Using the fact that addition and multiplication of kernels yield valid kernels:

$$
K' = \alpha K_1 + \beta K_2\\
K' = K_1K_2
$$

we can conclude that the exponential of a kernel is a kernel.